# GRIDVIEW- PASS IMAGE FROM ONE ACTIVTY TO ANOTHER ON ONCLICK EVENT?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview where i am loading images from URL
I want to select a image from Gridview and show it in ImageView of another activity.
How to do this?

Comment: I think you can attach onItemClickListener to gridview to know which image is clicked, get image url as string and send it via intent to next activity or save it in shared preferences so it can be used throughout all app.

Comment: you need to pass the bitmap in Intent's extra and get it like `getIntent().getParcelableExtra(name)`

Answer (score 1):

```
 GridView grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);



grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

          // here pass the image path 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
image_grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Display_Image_Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("img", arr_img[arg2]);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

**arr_img** is an array which is stored your Images.

From another class you get it and set on ImageView.